# Open file with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to see if a file exists, and then if it exists, I want to open the file, and see what it contains.

I have these methods:

```
def Utility.exist_request_xml(filexml)
  puts("exist_request_xml")
  if(File.exist?("#{PATH_WEBSERVICES_REQUEST}/#{filexml}"))
    puts 'file exists'
    puts(File.exist?("#{PATH_WEBSERVICES_REQUEST}/#{filexml}"))
  else
    puts 'file not exist'
  end
end


def Utility.open_request_xml(filexml)
  puts("open_request_xml")
  if(Utility.exist_request_xml(filexml))

    f=File.open("#{PATH_WEBSERVICES_REQUEST}/#{filexml}","r") 
    f.each_line do |line| 
      puts line 
    end
  else
    puts 'there is no file to open'
  end
end
```

The first method works. I cannot open the file in the second method. The problem is that, even if the file exists, because I recall the first method in the second, it doesn't open the file.

Can you help me?

Comment: are you getting a specific error?

Comment: No, it simply tells me "there is no file to open" but I am sure there is because with the first method I see that the file exist. The log show me this:
START TEST: 27/02/2019 17:09
test_wsdl
exist_request_xml
file exists
true
exist_response_xml
file exists
true
open_request_xml
exist_request_xml
file exists
true
there is no file to open
END TEST: 27/02/2019 17:09

Comment: Why are you prefixing the method with `Utility`. Is it a class or module name ?

Comment: It is a module I have to use

Comment: Just prefix with `self.` instead of `Utility.` to make it a module method.

Comment: I'd also suggest using either the auto-closing `File.open(...) do |f| ... end` block style or using `File.readlines(...)` if you don't care about the memory impact of loading the whole file.

Answer (score 6):

Your `Utility.exist_request_xml` method returns `nil`, which is falsey in an `if` statement, so it falls through to the else where you don't open the file.

It returns `nil` because by default the last evaluated expression is the return value and your last expression is an if. Similarly the return value of an if is the last thing *it* evaluates, which is a `puts` (in either branch). `puts` returns `nil`.

Return the value of the existence check instead:

```
def Utility.exist_request_xml filexml
  File.exist? "#{PATH_WEBSERVICES_REQUEST}/#{filexml}"
end
```

Comment: @AlessandroLopresti glad to help! Could you click the checkmark next to my answer if this solved your problem?